# Building a keyboad navigatable listview with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, listview

I am developing a listview with angular.js. The listview should be 'navigatable' with keyboard UP/DOWN arrow keys. The listview looks so far great, but my problem, is how to set the focus on the right element while navigating in the list. For example, how to focus the last element on the new page, after pressing UP arrow key or how to focus the first element on the new page, after pressing the DOWN arrow key.

Here is my markup

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as list" ng-init="start=0; end=5" >
<a prev-page="list.decrease()" next-page="list.increase()" href="#" class="list-group-item animate-repeat" ng-repeat="item in list.items | slice: start + list.next : end + list.next" tabindex="{{$index}}" navigatable-with-keyboard>
    {{item.title}}
            {{start + list.next}}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right to-right-side"></span>
</a>
```

And here the angular.js code

```
(function(){
var test = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    test.push({id: i, title: 'Item ' + i});

var myapp = angular.module('testTV', ['ngAnimate']);

myapp.filter('slice', function() {    
    return function(arr, start, end) {
        return arr.slice(start, end);
    };
});

myapp.controller('MainController', [function(){
    var list = this;
    list.items = test;
    list.next = 0;

    list.decrease = function(){
        //console.log(this.next);
        this.next -= 5;
    }
    list.increase = function(){
        //console.log(this.next);
        this.next += 5;
    }
    list.refresh = function(){
        list.items = [];
        for (var z = 101; z <= 111; z++)
            list.items.push({id: z, title: 'Item ' + z});
    }
}]);    
myapp.directive('navigatableWithKeyboard', function(){
       return {
           scope: {
               nextPage: '&',
               prevPage: '&',
           },
           link: function(scope, element, attribute){
               scope.$watch(attribute.tabindex, function() {
                   if(attribute.tabindex == 0)
                       element.focus();
               });
                element.on("keydown", function(event){
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        switch (event.keyCode) {
                            case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
                                element.next("a").focus();
                                if(scope.$parent.$last) scope.nextPage();
                                break;
                            case tvKey.KEY_UP:
                                element.prev("a").focus();
                                if(scope.$parent.$first) scope.prevPage();
                                break;
                            case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
                                scope.prevPage();
                                break;
                            case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
                                scope.nextPage();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    });                    
                }) ;
            }
        };
    });
})();

var tvKey = {
    KEY_POWER: 2085,
    KEY_MUTE: 2192,
    KEY_MIC: 2032,
    KEY_NUM1: 49,
    KEY_NUM2: 50,
    KEY_NUM3: 51,
    KEY_NUM4: 52,
    KEY_NUM5: 53,
    KEY_NUM6: 54,
    KEY_NUM7: 55,
    KEY_NUM8: 56,
    KEY_NUM9: 57,
    KEY_NUM0: 48,
    KEY_MENU: 122,
    KEY_BACK: 8,
    KEY_RETURN: 8,
    KEY_CHANNEL_PREV: 1009,
    KEY_CHANNEL_NEXT: 9,
    KEY_EXIT: 27,
    KEY_REFRESH: 116,
    KEY_UP: 38,
    KEY_DOWN: 40,
    KEY_LEFT: 37,
    KEY_RIGHT: 39,
    KEY_ENTER: 13,
    KEY_RW: 33,
    KEY_PAGE_UP: 33,
    KEY_FF: 34,
    KEY_PAGE_DOWN: 34,
    KEY_VOLUME_UP: 107,
    KEY_VOLUME_DOWN: 109,
    KEY_F1: 112,
    KEY_F2: 113,
    KEY_F3: 114,
    KEY_F4: 115,
    KEY_SET: 120,
    KEY_TV: 121,
    KEY_PHONE: 119,
    KEY_WEB: 123,
    KEY_REWIND: 2066,
    KEY_FORWARD: 2070,
    KEY_PLAY_PAUSE: 2082,
    KEY_STOP: 2083,
    KEY_RECORD: 2087,
    KEY_INFO: 2089,
    KEY_FRAME: 117,
    KEY_APP: 2076,
    KEY_USB_UNMOUNTED: 2081,
    KEY_USB_MOUNTED: 2080,
    KEY_DELETE: 46,
    KEY_YELLOW: 68,
    KEY_BLUE: 67,
    KEY_GREEN: 66,
    KEY_RED: 65
};
```

Here is the link to [`jsfiddle.net`](http://jsfiddle.net/r0_0t/4wx3tdxj/13/)